# Bubblesort in Python 3.2

Tags: python

I've just started with learning python today.
This is my first real programming language...
I tried to do a bubblesort but it always fails.
I don't know why...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
import random;

i = 0
x = 100
test = []

def createRandom():
        global i
        global test
        while i <= x:
                test.extend([random.randrange(1,100)]);
                i=i+1;
        return test;

def bubblesort():
        sorted=False;
        while sorted!=True:
                y = 0;
                l = len(test)-1
                print(l);
                while y < l:
                        sorted=True;
                        if test[y]<test[y+1]:
                                tmp = test[y]
                                test[y]=test[y+1];
                                test[y+1]=tmp;
                                y=y+1;
                                sorted=False;


createRandom();
bubblesort();
print(test);
```

Error:

```
    root@Debian:~/python3# ./bubblesort.py
100
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bubblesort.py", line 34, in <module>
    bubblesort();
  File "./bubblesort.py", line 25, in bubblesort
    if test[y]<test[y+1]:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you should move `sorted=True;` to the outer loop. Also, `;` not necessary.

Comment: Here's a tip - don't use `root` to run/test/debug things; use your own user account.

Comment: Also, move the `y=y+1` out of the `if`

Comment: @tobias_k, that's the answer

Comment: initialization hint: make your test list more pythonic with `test = range(100)` and then `random.shuffle(test)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, there are two problems:

- `y=y+1` needs to be outside of the `if` statement, otherwise you will run into an infinite loop as soon as there are two elements in correct order
- `sorted=True` should be in the outer loop, otherwise your sort will stop if the last two elements in the list are in sorted order

There are some other things that can be improved:

- in Python, there's no need to put a `;` after statements
- you can do swaps like `a, b = b, a`, without using a temporary variable
- don't use `global` variables so much, better pass them as parameters
- instead of `while x < y: ... x=x+1` better use `for x in range(y)`
- sorted order usually is from smallest to largest, so you should use `>` instead of `<`
- [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are great stuff; read about them!

Putting it all together, a simplified version could look like this:

```
import random

def createRandom():
    return [random.randrange(1,100) for i in range(100)]

def bubblesort(test):
    is_sorted = False
    while not is_sorted:
        is_sorted= True
        for y in range(len(test) - 1):
            if test[y] > test[y+1]:
                test[y], test[y+1] = test[y+1], test[y]
                is_sorted= False

lst = createRandom()
bubblesort(lst)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while y < l:
    sorted=True;
    if test[y]<test[y+1]:
        tmp = test[y]
        test[y]=test[y+1];
        test[y+1]=tmp;
        y=y+1;
        sorted=False;
```

You only do `y=y+1` if your IF statement is true!

Try putting `y=y+1` outside the if and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes that need to be made, otherwise looks good!

As tobias said, moev the sorted=True outside the inner while loop.  And you need to move the y = y + 1 to outside the if statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
import random;

i = 0
x = 100
test = []

def createRandom():
        global i
        global test
        while i <= x:
                test.extend([random.randrange(1,100)]);
                i=i+1;
        return test;

def bubblesort():
        sorted=False;
        while sorted!=True:
                y = 0;
                l = len(test)-1
                print(l);
                sorted=True;
                while y < l:
                        if test[y]<test[y+1]:
                                tmp = test[y]
                                test[y]=test[y+1];
                                test[y+1]=tmp;
                                sorted=False;
                        y=y+1;


createRandom();
bubblesort();
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the better approach to complete the bubbleSort.

```
def bubbleSort(L):

        for i in range(len(L)-1,0,-1):
                for j in range(i):
                        if L[j]>L[j+1]:
                                temp=L[j]
                                L[j]=L[j+1]
                                L[j+1]=temp

        print L
    print "List Sorted . END!!"
L=[4,5,6,7,2,3,8,7,9,6,7]
bubbleSort(L)
```

This approach is good upto a few thousands of elements. If you are looking for some bing number like 1M then this approach will take time to prove your results. Go for some other approach and let me know too ;)